# Jquery ajax call inside MVC

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I work with a self made framework...I want to make an ajax call with jquery and I don't know how to pass the url...I mean if i have controller "categories" and action "index" the ajax call would be like this?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/learning/categories/index/",

});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var controller = "categories";
var action = "index";
var myURL = "http://localhost/learning/" + controller + "/" + action + "/";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myURL 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your JavaScript in an ASP.NET MVC view?  If so, you can use Url.Action to generate the URL on the fly.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '<%: Url.Action("index", "categories")%>',
});
```

If your JavaScript is in a separate .js file, then you've added a bit more complexity.

My solution was to render the .js file dynamically (i.e. route scripts.js to an action method that returns a view with a contenttype of text/javascript).

I've also tried passing the URL from the rendered view to the .js file but this seemed messier than the above solution.

In MVC Conf on Tuesday, it was suggested that you simply avoid supporting both relative and absolute URLs - thus you could make assumptions about the base URL.  That works too...

Comment: sorry for not mentioning the framework is written in php and any documentation regarding ajax calls in mvc  would be great!

Comment: So are you calling an ASP.NET MVC method via JQuery/Ajax in a page rendered by PHP?  In this case you would have to hard-code or build the URL (you can build it if you know the application root, the controller, and the action - as long as the MVC app is using default routing rules).  You might also need to provide the parameters (data:) and the return type (dataType:) in your Ajax call.

Comment: actually I am not using at all ASP.NET just a customized version of the framework explained here [link](http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/30/write-your-own-php-mvc-framework-part-2/)

Comment: You might want to add a PHP tag to your question - you'll get more folks who might know that framework.  If the PHP framework supports something like Url.Action that generates the URL for you that would be best.  Otherwise you have to build the URL that corresponds to your routing for the controller's action method.